# users and expiration date

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc

I have a question that I hope someone can help me with, I would like to be able to search for how many paying members my website has at a specific date.

They belong to their own role "members" and there is an expiration date for each member. If they do not have an expiration date, they should also be listed.

Should I be able to use 2sxc module for this and would anyone tell me how to do?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to have an intermediate understanding of SQL and the tables/fields related to the results you are trying to achieve. Though it is possible to get done in 2sxc, I would recommend starting the effort the DNN Reports module. That should let you focus on getting the results you need in the SQL Query first (since the display part is auto/default. Then, once you have the right query, you could move it over to 2sxc (or any module that allows data to be queried and returned as a result (set)) and do something more useful.